# Bokeh : Plot a spectrogram

Tags: python, bokeh

I am new to Bookeh and I have a task to plot the spectrogram in bokeh.

I am using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html
to get the spectrogram.
In the above example they are using pcolormesh() of matplotlib to plot the spectrogram. How can I get the same(or equivalent) spectrogram plot in bokeh.

I have tried to get it done by plotting a heatmap by using the folowing code:

```
    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(raw_data, fs)
    i=0
    for freq in range(f.shape[0]):
        for time in range(t.shape[0]):
            df_spectogram.loc[i] = [f[freq],t[time],Sxx[freq][time]]
            i = i+1

    TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
    PALETTE = ['#081d58', '#253494', '#225ea8', '#1d91c0', '#41b6c4', '#7fcdbb', '#c7e9b4', '#edf8b1', '#ffffd9']
    mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=PALETTE, low=numpy.min(Sxx), high=numpy.max(Sxx))
    spectogram_figure = figure(title="Spectogram",x_axis_location="below", plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
               tools=TOOLS)
    spectogram_figure.background_fill_color = "#eaeaea"
    spectrogram_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Sxx=df_spectogram['Sxx'],Frequency=df_spectogram['Frequency'],Time=df_spectogram['Time']))
    spectogram_figure.circle(x="Time", y="Frequency", source=spectrogram_source, fill_color={'field': 'Sxx', 'transform': mapper}, line_color=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in the required way by changing

```
spectogram_figure.circle(x="Time", y="Frequency", source=spectrogram_source, fill_color={'field': 'Sxx', 'transform': mapper}, line_color=None)
```

to plot a rectangle with width equal to that of segment times and height of frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, where I tried to duplicate the example spectrogram code from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html

[Bokeh Spectrogram Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXYuA.png)

To generate the matplotlib spectrogram and then the bokeh spectrogram:

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.fftpack import fftshift
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import BasicTicker, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper, PrintfTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2) 
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.25*time) 
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*3e3*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)
df_spectogram = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Frequency","Time","Sxx"])

time = list(t)
freq = list(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(index = freq ,data = Sxx, columns = time)

plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns=['amp']).reset_index()

plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')

colors = ['#440154', '#404387', '#29788E', '#22A784', '#79D151', '#FDE724']
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df.amp.min(), high=df.amp.max())

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="Spectrogram",
           # x_range=time, y_range=freq,
            plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,
           tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('amp', '@amp%')])

p.circle(x="level_1", y="level_0", size=5,
       source=df,
       fill_color={'field': 'amp', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color=None)

show(p)
plt.show()
```